# Issue in JSON RCP

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, ethereum, blockchain, web3js

I am working on a chrome extension and using react for performing transactions on a blockchain.

Below is my code.

```
await userAbi.methods.setSpecificUserClickStatistics("0xC1295911653cF1616d16BD0ad87e55967e8df1d0").send({from:'0xC877D6a673ba306be8785e64D00C1Bff46dc66B1'});
```

I don't know what is the issue. But getting below error when check console.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're connecting to Infura, which doesn't support `eth_sendTransaction`.

Infura is a public node, so it doesn't know anyone's private key and thus can't sign transactions.

Comment: Thanks @smarx. Is there a way where I can perform the same transaction which I mentioned above.

Comment: You'd have to sign the transaction yourself with the account's private key.